# SOQL to get attachemnts

Tags: soql

i want to retrieve the attachments of SObject Account and also i was created a custom field(checkbox) named as is_read__c. 
Now, using SOQL is it possible to get attachments of Account from attachment SObject where condition is is_read__c = true

Comment: What have you tried so far? A direct answer to your question: Yes it is possible to get attachments of Account from attachment SObject. BUT there is no way to add a custom field to the attachment object so not sure what you are referring to there

Answer (score 4):

You can query for Accounts and Attachments in one Parent-Child SOQL Query.

SOQL:

`List<Account> accounts = [Select Id, is_read__c, (Select Id from Attachments) from Account where is_read__c = true];`

As commentators mentioned above you cannot add custom fields to the Attachment object.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm